# Need advice on use of IDENT_CURRENT('tablename') on ms sql query

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I have three tables-Employee,Contact and Login. Employee table has emp_id as primary key with identity value. Contact table has emp_id as foreign key which references to the emp_id of Employee table and Login table also has emp_id as foreign key that references to the emp_id of   the Employee table. All tables has primary key that auto increases as all of them are set as identity(1,1).

Here is my sql query:

```
create procedure [dbo].[sp_registerEmp] 
@start_date datetime,
@first_name varchar(50),
@middle_name varchar(50),
@last_name varchar(50),
@father_name varchar(50),   
@grandfather_name varchar(50),
@country varchar(20),
@mobile_no int,
@email_id varchar(30),
@designation varchar(30),
@username varchar(20),
@password varchar(15),
@security_question varchar(150),
@security_answer varchar(50)


as
begin

    begin try
        begin transaction

            insert into [dbo].[Employee]([start_date])
            values(@start_date)

            insert into [dbo].[Contact](first_name,middle_name,last_name,father_name,grandfather_name,
                                        country,mobile_no,email_id,emp_id)
            values(@first_name,@middle_name,@last_name,@father_name,@grandfather_name,
                    @country,@mobile_no,@email_id,SCOPE_IDENTITY());


            insert into [dbo].[Login](username,userpassword,security_question,security_answer,emp_id)
            values(@username,@password,@security_question,@security_answer,IDENT_CURRENT('Employee'));

        commit transaction
    end try

    begin catch

        rollback transaction

    end catch

end
```

Now my question is that as ident_current('tablename')returns the last identity value produced in that table regardless of the session and scope.Now using ident_current('tablename') may not give the desired emp_id and in those cases i may have login table that is meant for one user but is created for another user. I just want to have the emp_id for login table that is inserted by the first query of the transaction.How can i acheive this?

**Another problem is that when executing stored procedure from visual studio,eventhough there is error,primary key is increasing for each insert try regardless of failure and success.I want to do something like when there is error,primary key won't increase.How should i do this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just want to have the emp_id ... that is inserted by the first query of the transaction. How can i acheive this?

You can just declare a local variable to store the results of `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`. Then you can use this variable in subsequent statements:

```
...
begin transaction
declare @emp_id int

insert into [dbo].[Employee]([start_date])
values(@start_date)

-- store for later use    
set @emp_id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

insert into [dbo].[Contact](first_name,middle_name,last_name,father_name,grandfather_name,
                            country,mobile_no,email_id,emp_id)
values(@first_name,@middle_name,@last_name,@father_name,@grandfather_name,
        @country,@mobile_no,@email_id, @emp_id );
--- here ----------------------------> ^^^^^^^

insert into [dbo].[Login](username,userpassword,security_question,security_answer,emp_id)
values(@username,@password,@security_question,@security_answer, @emp_id );
--- here -----------------------------------------------------> ^^^^^^^

...
```

> I want to do something like when there is error,primary key won't increase.How should i do this?

I don't think there is an easy way to do this - you would have to re-seed the identity value after each error:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (<table_name>, RESEED)
```

I think this is error prone (are you going to call the above on all errors?), and not a good idea.  See also [DBCC CHECKIDENT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx) at MSDN.

Comment: Thank You chue x sir. For second problem,is there any way i can increment the value of primary key only if the transaction is successfull?

Comment: @shrawan_lakhe - I believe not. As I mention above, you have to reset the seed after an error.